# How to look for each column into another table column in Django/Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two tables,

User:
-name
-description

InterestingUser:
-keywords

I wish to check if any User's name is in InteretingUser keywords column, so when I do User.objects.all(), I also want to see if it is a interesting user, it is an interesting user if the username appears in InterestingUser table inside keywords column, also, keywords column is list of keywords separated by comma, so how do I figure out if it is a interesting user?

Comment: Please show what you have tried to do so far, and share the models

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life easier you should use a *many-to-one* relationship from Users to InterstingUser (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).
Matching the usernames based on keywords separated by commas is a bit coincidental and it will slow down your queries.

What would happen if some users get deactivated or deleted? You might end up constantly changing the filters to match the actual needs.